# Sharepoint 2013 Server December 2016 CU Known Issues

Tags: sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, patching

Is anyone aware of any known issues with the December 2016 CU for Sharepoint 2013 Server?

We installed the September 2015 CU previously which has borked in-place Search (results do not come back on the correct scope) but I've had no luck finding a fix for that or any indication of a known issue (we have two farms with the September 2015 CU with the same problem, and two without it that don't have the issue).

Our plan at the moment is to install the December 2016 CU and hope it fixes the issue but I'm a bit cautious it might introduce other issues, or just not fix the existing issue.

Restoring the farm from a backup before September 2015 CU was installed is unfortunately not an option as it happened too far back and the client would lose a ton of data.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There is a lot of patches in between sep 15 - dec 16. Best is to see if you can find anything for each patch notes at Todd's blog (Bugs, Notes, and Regressions). http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346

Comment: No mention of my specific issue on any of those I'm afraid :( I'd normally think it's something specific to the farm but I have two farms with the same patch showing the same issue so I doubt that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of your issue represented in you have installed `September 2015 CU` before installing `August 2015 CU`.

`September 2015 CU` has been released without "Server" or "Uber" packages that mean if you are not in an urgent need for a fix included in `September 2015 CU` you should consider **waiting** for a CU release that includes "Server" or "Uber" packages.

So It is highly recommended to install `August 2015 CU` before installing `September 2015 CU`! for more details check [September 2015 CU for SharePoint 2013 is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/12/13/december-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/) **Note:** [Uber packages for September 2015 CU for SharePoint 2013 have been released on 2015-09-17](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2986213/september-17,-2015,-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-server-2013-kb2986213) and Maybe you install it before the Uber was released.

So one of the available options is to go ahead to install [December 2016 CU for SharePoint 2013 product family is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/12/13/december-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/) that should solve your current issue because it includes all SharePoint 2013 fixes and as the previous CU it requires SP 2013 SP1 to be installed first.

**Keep in mind,**

- Once the installation is finished, Start running the `SharePoint Configuration Wizard (PSConfig)` on the main application server that hosts the central administration then continue with other servers at the same time without order.For more details how to patch your farm check [Find Farm Patch Level](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)
- Generally, I advise you Before patching your farm, you should first read the prerequisites for the CU carefully at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't know what your source is on having to install the August 2015 CU first - the Sept 2015 CU download page makes no mention of this and explicitly states all previous CUs are included and only SP1 is required - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2986213/september-17,-2015,-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-server-2013-kb2986213

Comment: Hi @ThomasGass Could you please take a look at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/09/08/september-2015-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-is-available-for-download/ ? that my source :)

Comment: Ah fair enough... MS could have made this information clearer on the actual download page! Typical.

Comment: I agree, but this blog is a trusted source, I have mentioned the source in the answer too. where the September 2015 CU was released first without uber. then on 17/09 it was released, hope now there is no confusion

Comment: Installing the Aug CU is not necessary prior to installing a newer version (such as any 2016 or 2017 CUs). In addition, the information about running the Config Wizard on the CA box first is not correct. The order of running the Config Wizard in the farm does not matter.

Comment: Hi @TrevorSeward what I have said, if you need to install a CU you should check its prerequisites first, and if the CU does not have Uber package that means you need to install the previous CU first that in this case is Aug 2015 or wait the next CU with Uber,  so I didn't say it's necessary to installing a newer version, it just a recommendation in case of installing Sep 2015 CU without Uber package as Stefan Goßner said.Meanwhile, the question owner asking about the prerequisites of installing Dec 2016 .so I suggest going ahead installing because it includes all SharePoint 2013 fixes.

Comment: Regarding the order I think Stefan Goßner is a trusted source like you, so should you check his comment on February 28, 2017, at 10:52 am. He said The guidance for PSConfig is unchanged: start with the app server hosting the central admin. Ref: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/09/09/why-we-recommend-require-to-run-the-configuration-wizard-also-for-security-fixes/